# How do you test Game Center features for your next update once the app is live

Tags: iphone, game-center

I just released my iphone app that has game center multiplayer integration, and I am preparing for my next update. I have the bundle id for the test version of my app different from the one that is live, so it will not overwrite the live version. However I would not be able to access game center features, and I don't believe it's possible to attach 2 bundle ids to the same game center account. I was wondering what would be the best way to test game center features for my next update, when my app is already on the app store.